# xtabs counts with NA and na.action = na.pass in R

Tags: r, na

I have the following `data.frame`:

```
x <- data.frame(A = c("Y", "Y", "Z", NA),
                B = c(NA, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
                C = c(TRUE, TRUE, NA, FALSE))
```

I need to compute the following table:

```
A     B  C
Y     1  2
Z     0  0
<NA>  1  0
```

However I am unable to achieve this result with `xtabs`, even with `na.action = na.pass`:

```
xtabs(formula = cbind(B, C) ~ A,
      data = x,
      addNA = TRUE,
      na.action = na.pass)

A       B  C
  Y        2
  Z     0   
  <NA>  1  0
```

From `?xtabs`:

> na.action
>   a function which indicates what should happen when the data
>   contain NAs. If unspecified, and addNA is true, this is set to
>   na.pass. When it is na.pass and formula has a left hand side (with
>   counts), sum(*, na.rm = TRUE) is used instead of sum(*) for the
>   counts.
>
> addNA
>   logical indicating if NAs should get a separate level
>   and be counted, using addNA(*, ifany=TRUE) and setting the default for
>   na.action.

As a workaround, I can replace the `NA` by `FALSE`:

```
x[is.na(x$B), "B"] <- FALSE
x[is.na(x$C), "C"] <- FALSE

xtabs(formula = cbind(B, C) ~ A,
      data = x,
      addNA = TRUE)

A      B C
  Y    1 2
  Z    0 0
  <NA> 1 0
```

Or I can use aggregate:

```
aggregate(formula = cbind(B, C) ~ addNA(A),
          data = x,
          FUN = sum,
          na.rm = TRUE,
          na.action = na.pass)

  addNA(A) B C
1            Y 1 2
2            Z 0 0
3         <NA> 1 0
```

But how get this table with `xtabs` without replacing `NA` by `FALSE`?

Comment: Follow-up question (bug in documentation): https://stackoverflow.com/q/61240049

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `na.action=na.pass` to `na.action=NULL`.

```
xtabs(formula = cbind(B, C) ~ A,
      data = x,
      addNA = TRUE,
      na.action = NULL)

A      B C
  Y    1 2
  Z    0 0
  <NA> 1 0
```

Comment: Thank you verry much! I tried everything except that!