# Inconsistency of na.action between xtabs and aggregate in R

Tags: r, aggregate, na, counting

I have the following data.frame:

```
x <- data.frame(A = c("Y", "Y", "Z", NA),
                B = c(NA, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
                C = c(TRUE, TRUE, NA, FALSE))
```

And I need to compute the following table with `xtabs`:

```
A      B C
  Y    1 2
  Z    0 0
  <NA> 1 0
```

[I was told to use `na.action = NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56237951/xtabs-counts-with-na-and-na-action-na-pass-in-r), which indeed returns the table I need:

```
xtabs(formula = cbind(B, C) ~ A,
      data = x,
      addNA = TRUE,
      na.action = NULL)

A      B C
  Y    1 2
  Z    0 0
  <NA> 1 0
```

However, `na.action = na.pass` returns a different table:

```
xtabs(formula = cbind(B, C) ~ A,
      data = x,
      addNA = TRUE,
      na.action = na.pass)

A       B  C
  Y        2
  Z     0   
  <NA>  1  0
```

But the documentation of `xtabs` says:

> na.action
>   When it is na.pass and formula has a left hand side (with counts),
>   sum(*, na.rm = TRUE) is used instead of sum(*) for the counts.

With `aggregate`, `na.action = na.pass` returns the expected result (and also `na.action = NULL`):

```
aggregate(formula = cbind(B, C) ~ addNA(A),
          data = x,
          FUN = sum,
          na.rm = TRUE,
          na.action = na.pass) # same result with na.action = NULL

  addNA(A) B C
1            Y 1 2
2            Z 0 0
3         <NA> 1 0
```

Although I get the table I need with `xtabs`, I do not understand the behavior of `na.action` in `xtabs` from the documentation. So my questions are:

- Is the behavior of `na.action` in `xtabs` consistent with the documentation? Unless I am missing something, `na.action = na.pass` does not result in `sum(*, na.rm = TRUE)`.
- Is `na.action = NULL` documented somewhere?
- In `xtabs` source code there is `na.rm <- identical(naAct, quote(na.omit)) || identical(naAct, na.omit) || identical(naAct, "na.omit")`. But I saw nothing for `na.action = na.pass` and `na.action = NULL`. How do `na.action = na.pass` and `na.action = NULL` work?

Comment: you can check `a function which indicates what should happen when the data contain NAs. If unspecified, and addNA is true, this is set to na.pass. When it is na.pass and formula has a left hand side (with counts), sum(*, na.rm = TRUE) is used instead of sum(*) for the counts.`

Comment: Thank you, but that is exactly what I do not understand. The documentation do not seem to be consistent with the behavior, or at least I fail to understand the documentation. I edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's difficult to give a cannonical answer without describing how `xtabs` works. If we step through the main points of its source code, we'll see clearly what's going on.

After some basic type checking, the call to `xtabs` works internally by first creating a data frame of all the variables contained in your formula using `stats::model.frame`, and it is to this that the `na.action` parameter is passed.

The way it does this is quite clever. `xtabs` first copies the call you made to it via `match.call`, like this:

```
m <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
```

Then it strips out the parameters that don't need passed to `stats::model.frame` like this:

```
m$... <- m$exclude <- m$drop.unused.levels <- m$sparse <- m$addNA <- NULL
```

As promised in the help file, if `addNA` is `TRUE` and `na.action` is missing, it will now default to `na.pass`:

```
    if (addNA && missing(na.action)) 
        m$na.action <- quote(na.pass)
```

Then it changes the function to be called from `xtabs` to `stats::model.frame` like this:

```
m[[1L]] <- quote(stats::model.frame)
```

So the object `m` is a call (and is also a standalone reprex), which in your case looks like this:

```
stats::model.frame(formula = cbind(B, C) ~ A, data = list(A = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("Y", "Z"), class = "factor"), B = c(NA, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), 
C = c(TRUE, TRUE, NA, FALSE)), na.action = NULL)
```

Note that your `na.action = NULL` has been passed to this call. This has the effect of keeping all `NA` values in the frame. When the above call is evaluated, it gives this data frame:

```
eval(m)
#>   cbind(B, C).B cbind(B, C).C    A
#> 1            NA          TRUE    Y
#> 2          TRUE          TRUE    Y
#> 3         FALSE            NA    Z
#> 4          TRUE         FALSE <NA>
```

Note that this is the same result you would get if you passed `na.action = na.pass`:

```
stats::model.frame(formula = cbind(B, C) ~ A, data = list(A = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("Y", "Z"), class = "factor"), B = c(NA, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), 
C = c(TRUE, TRUE, NA, FALSE)), na.action = na.pass)
#>   cbind(B, C).B cbind(B, C).C    A
#> 1            NA          TRUE    Y
#> 2          TRUE          TRUE    Y
#> 3         FALSE            NA    Z
#> 4          TRUE         FALSE <NA>
```

However, if you passed `na.action = na.omit`, you would only be left with a single row, since only row 2 has no `NA` values.

In any case, the "model frame" result is stored in the variable `mf`. This is then split into the independent variable(s), - in your case, column A, and the response variable - in your case `cbind(B, C)`.

The response is stored in `y` and the variable in `by`:

```
        i <- attr(attr(mf, "terms"), "response")
        by <- mf[-i]
        y <- mf[[i]]
```

Now, `by` is processed to ensure each independent variable is a factor, and that any `NA` values are converted into factor levels if you have specified `addNA = TRUE`:

```
    by <- lapply(by, function(u) {
        if (!is.factor(u)) 
            u <- factor(u, exclude = exclude)
        else if (has.exclude) 
            u <- factor(as.character(u), levels = setdiff(levels(u), 
                exclude), exclude = NULL)
        if (addNA) 
            u <- addNA(u, ifany = TRUE)
        u[, drop = drop.unused.levels]
    })
```

Now we come to the crux. The `na.action` is used again to determine how the `NA` values in the response variable will be counted. In your case, since you passed `na.action = NULL`, you will see that `naAct` will get the value stored in `getOption("na.action")`, which if you have never changed it, should be set to `na.omit`. This in turn will cause the value of the variable `na.rm,` to be `TRUE`:

```
    naAct <- if (!is.null(m$na.action)) {
        m$na.action
    }else {getOption("na.action", default = quote(na.omit))}
    na.rm <- identical(naAct, quote(na.omit)) || identical(naAct, 
        na.omit) || identical(naAct, "na.omit")
```

Note that if you had passed `na.action = na.pass`, then `na.rm` would be `FALSE` if you trace this piece of code.

Finally, we come to the section where your `xtabs` table is built using `sum` inside a `tapply`, which is itself inside an `lapply`.

```r
lapply(as.data.frame(y), tapply, by, sum, na.rm = na.rm, default = 0L)
```

You can see that the `na.rm` variable is used to determine whether to remove `NA`s from the columns before attempting to sum them. The result of this `lapply` is then coerced into the final cross tab.

---

So how does this answer your question?

It is true when the documentation says that if you don't pass an `na.action`, it will default to `na.pass`. However, the `na.action` is used in two places: once in the call to `model.frame` and once to determine the value of `na.rm`. It is very clear from the source code that if `na.action` is `na.pass`, then `na.rm` will be `FALSE`, so you will miss out on the counts of any response groups containing `NA` values. This is the opposite of what is written in the help file.

The only way round this is to pass `na.action = NULL`, since this will allow `model.frame` to keep `NA` values, but will also cause the `sum` function to default to `na.rm`.

---

**TL;DR** The documentation for `xtabs` is wrong on this point.

Comment: Thank you very much for this excellent, clear, and detailed answer! I am waiting for the deadline before awarding the bounty, but so far you have won it! I am going to report a bug to improve the documentation.

Comment: @Thomas thank you. I think it would be better if they changed the function to match the documentation rather than the other way around?

Comment: I agree. Here is the bug report: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17770. Do not hesitate to step in!

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry I'm only joining now.  Indeed, the last half dozen changes to xtabs() were all by me, so I have to take responsibility here, too.

Delving into all variants and ramifications of `xtabs()` always takes some time which I've not taken yet (this time; of course did back then..).

But you finally deserve an answer:

- Yes, there's bug -- either in the R code or in the documentation (and that "or" is inclusive .. ;-)
- my current gut feeling is pointing to a bug in the help (file) rather than the implementation
- R's bugzilla is the place we should get into details about this, not the least because that's  "wired" to the R Core team's channels.
- --> follow up there: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17770.